# How to smoothly move an image on the x and y axis if props is true?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have an image on my page which needs to move on the `x` and `y` axis in the shape of a parenthesis curve '('. By this I mean that it starts, for example, at certain position with `top: 0px; left: 100px;,` then if a property passed to this image is true, the image moves to the left where the `left becomes 80px` and the `top becomes 30px;` and then it goes back to the origina `left: position of a 100x and top is 60px`;

I am using React with styled components and keyframes inside the styled component. I tried with multiple phases in the keyframes but my animation is not smooth at all, it leads to pauses when the percentage level is reached before going to the next keyframe and makes the animation very buggy and it has to be smooth.

Here is the code I tried:

```
const Image = styled.img`
  width: 78px;
  height: 130px;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 195px;
  left: 273px;
  transform-origin: center 20%;
  opacity: 1;
  will-change: transform;

  ${(props) => props.status
    && css`
      animation: moveElement ${props.animationDuration}s forwards ease-in-out;
    `}

  ${(props) => !props.status
    && css`
      animation: moveElementReverse ${props.animationDuration}s forwards ease-in-out;
    `}

  @keyframes moveElement {
    0% {
      transform: translate(0, 0);
      border: solid 2px white;
    }

    25% {
      transform: translate(-5px, 0);
      border: solid 2px purple;
    }

    50% {
      transform: translate(-10px, 20px);
      border: solid 2px orange;
    }

    75% {
      transform: translate(-5px, 45px);
      border: solid 2px green;
    }

    100% {
      transform: translate(0, 65px);
      border: solid 2px red;
    }
  }

  @keyframes moveElementReverse {
    0% {
      transform: translate(0, 65px);
      border: solid 2px red;
    }

    25% {
      transform: translate(-5px, 45px);
      border: solid 2px green;
    }

    50% {
      transform: translate(-10px, 20px);
      border: solid 2px orange;
    }

    75% {
      transform: translate(-5px, 0);
      border: solid 2px purple;
    }

    100% {
      transform: translate(0, 0);
      border: solid 2px white;
    }
  }
`;
```

At first I did try with `x` and `y` movement but now as you can see I am using `transform: translate` but the result is the same